# After divide to many files I lost polish signs

Tags: php, wordpress, character, polish

I'm writting a plugin for Wordpress. I had 1 file plugin.php and it works perfectly. I divide plugin.php to other files for better clarity. I wrote some lines

```
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/plugin-Lista.php';
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/plugin-Ajax.php';
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/plugin-Edycja.php';
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/plugin-Nowy.php';
```

Everything is working now except one thing - I lose polish characters like śćżź etc. Whats happend wrong? How to solve this problem?

Regards,

Comment: [Think UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I think this would be a UTF-8 problem where you are losing some special characters. Take a look at @Fred -ii-'s link

Comment: But before when my plugin contains only 1 file everything was right. I have Wordpress with Polish language pack since I install them. I'll check this link and I'll write what happend next :)
BTW: Sorry for my grammar.

Comment: Hmm maybe require_once encoding from UTF-8 to sth else?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it :)
My Visual Studio saves file with another encoding than UTF-8. That's all.

Hope I'll help somebody with this self-answer :D

Regards,